# Inserting data from a textbox in a userform to a cell and looping to the next cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, input

How do I push data from my textbox in the userform to a cell?

I want to loop through the column allowing the user to input data into each cell in the column until they are done entering their data.

I tried to concatenate a counter variable with the column letter but that didn't work.

```vb
Dim initCount As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim VesselCellName As String
initCount = 2
counter = initCount
counter = counter + 1
VesselCellName = "A" & counter
Range(VesselCellName).Value = AddInvTxtBox.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you run this sub, you set your "counter" initially to 2, then you add +1 to the value so you'll always loop through the same cell A3.

If you just need the first free row to populate you could "find" the last row.

```vb
initCount = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'cells(row#,col#), 
counter = initCount + 1
```

initCount will be the last row in column1 (=A), then you'll add +1 for the next free row.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub AddItem_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim Counter As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet 1")
Counter = sht.Range("A" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find the index of the last used row in column A 
sht.Range("A" & Counter + 1).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

End Sub
```